# Multiple conditions for one field in MySQL WHERE

Tags: mysql

I have a table some thing like below

```
type
-------
|name 
|name
|address
|address 
|name
|null 
|null
|null 
|name
|rollnumber
```

now i want this I want all the type but expect name

```
WHERE `type` != 'rollnumber'
```

In this list, I want every  thing even null  but not rollnumber

I'm hoping for a better way to do that, so I could compare `type`?

Thanks!

Comment: just add `or type is null`

Comment: while adding OR type is null, I got list of NULL only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `IS NULL`:

```
WHERE (`type` != 'rollnumber' OR `type` IS NULL)
```

If you want to exclude records with type `name`:

```
WHERE (`type` != 'name' OR `type` IS NULL)
```